# iterm2 change color of tab when running screen on remote server

Tags: bash, iterm2

I couldn't find a script which changes the color of my iterm2 tab if it has a screen open on a remote server. Could this be acheived without shell integration?

I did use triggers in my profile. I can trigger the tab that there is a screen running on this screen, based on the last line in the shell which has the gnu-screen's hardstatus printed on.
I then tried to link the command `echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;255\a"` but it doesn't seem to get picked up by iterm2.
Does someone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `run command` does exactly what it says: executes a command. It has no relation to your current tty, so you're just echoing into the void.

To run it inside the tty you'd need `send text` with an added newline: `echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;255\a"\n`
But `\0` escapes to the current match so you'll have to escape that to avoid recursion. And even then I guess it would pollute the session from triggering every time the status line gets updated.

I think the way to go would be trigger a silent coprocess with the corresponding osascript tell.

Answer (score 1):

to support random color automaticly when using `color` without argument

add the following lines to `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
PRELINE="\r\033[A"

function random {
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
}

function color {
    case $1 in
    green)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;57\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;197\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;77\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    red)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;270\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;60\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;83\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    orange)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;227\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;143\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;10\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    *)
    random
    esac
}

#color    #uncomment to enable automatically set random color when tab created
```

After each time a new iterm2 tab created, use command `color` to automaticly give it a new/random color.

if you want the iterm2-tab color set automatically whenever it is created, then .just add `color` to then end of `.zshrc` / `.profile` or just after the `function color`

Specificly on your question. you can add these settings on your server. and when you ssh on the server terminal, the iterm2 tab color changes.